# Issue with Paypal sandbox merchantpaymentweb: no style and JS errors

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been using PHP REST API SDK to work on the Paypal sandbox for a few days the first 2 weeks of October (and everything worked great), but when I came back to work on this project today, I had problem with the redirect URL to confirm the payment.

HTML seems OK but there is no style or picture and the form is displayed in simple HTML blocks. The JS console also returns errors like:

```
ReferenceError: PAYPAL is not defined merchan...3e80dcc (ligne 21)
ReferenceError: YUD is not defined merchan...3e80dcc (ligne 23, col. 17)
ReferenceError: PAYPAL is not defined merchan...3e80dcc (ligne 46)
ReferenceError: s is not defined merchan...3e80dcc (ligne 52)
```

Do you know if something change on this page? Requiring new parameters? Or is there a work in progress on this page?

Comment: Are you using chrome beta browser? If yes, you may try chrome production version once.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, in both Chrome and Firefox (both the current stable version).  Well, also the same, in Firefox it also says "YAHOO is not defined".

Comment: I tested this morning, still not working in Firefox but it works in Chrome (I did not try it last week)...

Comment: Same problem in Firefox! Works in Chromium.

Comment: Same Here. Broke in FireFox but fine in Chrome.

Comment: Coming back on the project and it seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I too have been seeing the same JS errors which I think are breaking the page.
Sent a message off to PayPal support and will update when/if I get an answer.

Comment: Just got this from PayPal support:
There are some issues with the sandbox that might have caused the problem when using firefox browser 33.X.

The engineers are already working towards a resolution.

Please consider using another browser as a workaround. Or you can try to modify the config setting in the firefox settings:

1) In the firefox URL, type "about:config" 
2) Search for "network.http.accept-encoding"
3) Change the value to "deflate;q=0"

We do apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Thanks!